# Help Simulating Random Effects in SAS

Tags: sas, simulation, random-effects-model

I'm trying to create a simulation of drug concentration based on the dose of a drug given.  I have some preliminary data and I used a random effects model to analyze the relationship between log(dose), predicting log(drug concentration), modelling subject as a random effect.  The results of that analysis are below.  I want to take these results and simulate similar data in SAS, so I can look at the effect of changing doses on the resulting concentration of drug in the body.  I know that when I simulate the data, I need to ensure the random slope is correlated with the random intercept, but I'm unsure exactly how to do that.

Random effects:

```
Formula: ~LDOS | RANDID  
Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization  
           StdDev             Corr   
(Intercept) 0.15915378        (Intr)  
LDOS        0.01783609          0.735  
Residual    0.05790635      

Fixed effects: LCMX ~ LDOS  
            Value   Std.Error  DF   t-value      p-value  
(Intercept) 3.340712     0.04319325   16    77.34339        0  
LDOS        1.000386      0.01034409   11    96.71090        0  

Correlation:  
             (Intr)  
LDOS -0.047
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coding in SAS. If improved to meet the standards of SO it would be appropriate there. For other forms of help with SAS questions, please visit our [SAS resource summary](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/816).

Comment: Re the edit: Are you now asking a statistical question about simulating data for a random effects model?  And if you are, does your reference to correlation refer to a requirement you are *imposing* on the model (and if so, why?) or are you quoting something you believe must be true?  (I suspect you might be confusing the properties of the model with the properties of the *estimates*, which is ok--we can answer that--but some clarification about this point is needed.)

Comment: @whuber, yes, I have edited my post to clarify that I'm asking a statistical question about simulating the data for a random effects model.  I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking.  What I am trying to ask is how I would simulate data that reflects the results of the mixed model I ran on my preliminary data.  I think it is a statistical question because I need help understanding the way that the fixed effects, random effects, and correlation can be integrated into the final model.  I was originally asking for code because I often find examples easier to understand.